# How to do partial update of object in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a ressource called `Vehicle` given by the model:

```
class Vehicle(models):
    doors = models.Integerfield
    brand = models.CharField
```

From a different host, I send a `PUT` request to update one of the properties using the `requests` package:

```
requests.put(remote_host + "/" + vehicle_id, data={"brand":"New Brand"})
```

**Note**: The doors were not updated.

Now on the remote I'd like to update whatever properties are being sent. This would happend in `views.py` of the `Vehicle` ressource:

```
def update(self, request):
    vehicle_to_update = Vehicle.objects.get(pk=self.request.data["id"])

    # How do I know here, that it is only "brand" that is being updated?
    # Do I need to check for every possible property and see if a value was provided?
    vehicle_to_update.brand = self.request.data["brand"]
    vehicle_to_update.save()
```

Comment: You can use serializers for this: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates